# opposite of openURL to close web

Tags: ios, swift

How do I close openURL once I open it?

I'm looking at the docs but there's no other method listed

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623073-application?language=objc

I can open it below

```
 UIApplication.shared.open(authURL, options: [:], completionHandler:nil)
```

but is there a function to close it programatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call that method, the OS switches to the Safari app and passes it the URL you provided. Once you call that method, you no longer have control and the user has to get back to your app on their own.

You might want to look into presenting a `SFSafariViewController` instead to keep the user inside your app.